# system does not sleep and does not wake up

Tags: gui, suspend, amd-graphics, sleep

I recently bought a new HP ENVY x360 with AMD Ryzen 5 2500U CPU. So many driver support problems on Linux. I tried lots of distributions but none works.

The main problem is that the laptop won't sleep, the screen just goes off but the fans keep working on full speed and there is no way to wake it up again except by force shutdown.

Interestingly, I once messed up the desktop environment installation and the system booted to a terminal interface. There, if I close the lid, the system appears to sleep. The screen goes off, the fans go off, and the power button starts blinking, opening the lid took me back to the terminal interface as normal.

By the way, the touchscreen also doesn't work, if that's related by any means.

**Update**
Actually, sleep in terminal worked a few times, then last time it gave me a systemd-coredump. some parts of it (I can't copy from there)

```
systemd-coredump[6605]: MESSAGE=process 250 (systemd-journal) of user 0 dumped core
xhci_pci_suspend returns -110 failed
hcd_pci suspend returns -110
pci_pm_suspend return -110
PM:Device 0000:04:00.4 failed to suspend async: error -110
[drm:gfx_v9_0_hw_fini [amdgpu]] *Error* KCQ disabled failed
PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
[drm:sdma_v4_0_ring_test_ib [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: IB test timedout
```

Comment: The touchscreen is unrelated and managed by a different driver.  You can get it going with some effort: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198715.